# Let $w\in G_{18}$ be a primitive root of unity. Prove that $w^{16} \sum_{j=1}^{17}(w^3 \overline{w})^{3j+1}$ is imaginary pure.

Tags: complex-numbers, primitive-roots

This is what I've got:

$$w^3\overline{w}=w^3w^{-1}=w^2 \iff \\ w^{16} \sum_{j=1}^{17}(w^3 \overline{w})^{3j+1} = w^{16}w^2\sum_{j=1}^{17}w^{6j} = \bigg( \sum_{j=0}^{17}w^{6j} \bigg) - 1$$

Given that $18 = 6\times 3$, we know that $w^6 \in G_3$ is another primitive root of unity.

How can I move on from here?

Comment: Prove that $\overline{z} =-z$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3270387/let-w-in-g-24-be-a-primitive-root-find-every-n-in-mathbbn-such-that?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008570/help-with-problem-let-w-a-15th-primitive-root-of-unity-find-all-n-in-bbb?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053281/find-sum-i-0k-1win-in-terms-of-n-in-bbb-n-being-w-in-bbb-c-a?rq=1

Comment: $$\overline{\sum_{j=0}^{17}w^{6j}  - 1} = - \sum_{j=0}^{17}w^{6j} + 1 \iff \\ \sum_{j=0}^{17}w^{12j} + w^{6j} = 2 \ $$